# Issue comparing String to array, then returning value from a second array?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have created a piece of code in c# that takes an incoming phone number, and presents this as variable `lineuri`.

There is then an array containing each of the possible international Dialling Prefixes (e.g. 44 for the uk, 00 for the US e.t.c.

However, in order for this to function, i need to present to the user in a message box the country that the incoming call is coming from.

Essentially, i guess i need to take variable `LineUri`, and compare it to the Array of international number prefixes. If this matches, i then need a method of returning the Country Name from a second Array containing the names of each country?

Apologies if this is overly wordy - first time posting on this site.

If any further information is required, more than happy to help.

Appreciate any help you are able to offer - Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Use a Dictionary instead, then you can simple "Look up" the Country name without having 2 arrays.

Comment: +1 @dognose Dictionary is the most appropriate for lookups

Comment: As @dognose suggested, use a dictionary. Probably `Dictionary<string,string>` where the key is the country code and the value is the country

Comment: To check first characters of the `lineuri` against, you can use the `StartWith` methods of the string class. To the country name having the phone code, you can use `Dictionary` data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use an array. You need a keyed collection:

```
Dictionary<string,string> countriesByDialingCode = new Dictionary<string,string>();

...

countriesByDialingCode.Add("00", "USA");
countriesByDialingCode.Add("44", "USA");

...

string country = countriesByDialingCode["44"];
```